# Removing patterns in list

Tags: python

I have a list as following:

```
list=[80,"error",100,74,72,71,"error",39,38,63,"error",82,"error",62,75,23,77,87,"error",36]
```

and I want to remove "error" from the list :

```
llist=len(list)

for i in range(llist):
     if list[i]=="error":
         del list[i]
         llist-=1

print(list)
```

but the compiler still display,"if list[i]=="error":
IndexError: list index out of range".

Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your fix**:

```
llist=len(list_)

for i in range(llist):
    try:
         if list_[i]=="error":
             del list_[i]
             llist-=1
    except IndexError:
        pass
print(list_)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[80, 100, 74, 72, 71, 39, 38, 63, 82, 62, 75, 23, 77, 87, 36]
```

**Suggested**:

Looks like you only need the `numbers` from the list:

```
import numbers
print([x for x in list_ if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[80, 100, 74, 72, 71, 39, 38, 63, 82, 62, 75, 23, 77, 87, 36]
```

**OR**:

```
print([num for num in list_ if isinstance(num, (int,float))])
```

Answer (score 2):

First don't use keyword `list` as variable name. Then conditional list comprehension is an easy way to do it:

```
my_list = [i for i in my_list if i != "error"]
```

Your problem here is that you are modifying the list length while trying to iterate over it. Perfect recipe for errors...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `remove` function.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'error', 'c']
l.remove('error')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list1 = [i for i in list1 if i != 'error']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
>>> list1=[80,"error",100,74,72,71,"error",39,38,63,"error",82,"error",62,75,23,77,87,"error",36]
>>> filter(lambda a: a != "error", list1)
[80, 100, 74, 72, 71, 39, 38, 63, 82, 62, 75, 23, 77, 87, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the last line, you're using "print(list)" but list is not your variable, even list can't be a variable.
2. You're changing the list after remove a element, dont do it. With the remove element is ready